# remove images having low resolution

Tags: linux, command-line, images

I wonder if there is a way to recursively delete images from a directory, which have resolution less than I desire, using command-line tools (Fedora 19)?

For example, I want to keep images which have at least 3000px horizontal and 2000px vertical, and delete any other ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible purely `bash` solution, depending on the command `identify` from `ImageMagick` to tell the image resolution:

```
( find . -type f | xargs identify ) | while read i
do
  fn1=${i%%[*}
  fn=${i%% *}
  tail=${i#* * }
  size=${tail%% *}
  xsize=${size%%x*}
  ysize=${size##*x}
  if [[ ( $xsize -le 3000 ) || ( $ysize -le 2000 ) ]]
  then
    rm "$fn"
  fi
done
```

However, I'd totally make a backup first and then use something more powerful to parse (and double-check) the output of `identify` before automatically deleting files, like `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of @The Vee, here's a oneliner that finds all the files exactly like you want, provided you have ImageMagick, awk, sed, grep, cut, xargs and find installed:

`( find . -type f | xargs identify ) | grep -E '^[.][^ ]+? [^ ]+? [0-9]+?x[0-9]+? ' | sed -re 's/^([.][^ ]+?) [^ ]+? ([0-9]+?)x([0-9]+?) .*$/\2 \3 \1/g' | while read resolution; do resx=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $1 }'); resy=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $2 }'); if [[ ( $resx -lt 3000 ) || ( $resy -lt 2000 ) ]]; then echo "$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"; fi; done`

---

Explanation:

```bash
(
  # Recursively print filenames in the current directory
  find . -type f | \
  # Pipe them into xargs which runs "identify" for each file
  xargs identify
 ) | \
# Only keep the files that have been identified  
grep -E '^[.][^ ]+? [^ ]+? [0-9]+?x[0-9]+? ' | \
# Extract filename, width and height using RegEx into the format "<width> <height> <filename>". The filename is at the end to account for spaces in the filename which will be handled by using `cut`
sed -re 's/^([.][^ ]+?) [^ ]+? ([0-9]+?)x([0-9]+?) .*$/\2 \3 \1/g' | \
# For each of these lines extracted, do the following
while read resolution; do
  # Extract the width (first number)
  resx=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $1 }')
  # Extract the height (second number)
  resy=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $2 }')
  # Do the resolution check (use lower than, instead of lower equals)
  if [[ ( $resx -lt 3000 ) || ( $resy -lt 2000 ) ]]; then
    # Print the filename
    echo "$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"
  fi
done
```

The code above only prints the filenames, so if you want to delete them it's as easy as and piping it into `xargs`:

```
( find . -type f | xargs identify ) | grep -E '^[.][^ ]+? [^ ]+? [0-9]+?x[0-9]+? ' | sed -re 's/^([.][^ ]+?) [^ ]+? ([0-9]+?)x([0-9]+?) .*$/\2 \3 \1/g' | while read resolution; do resx=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $1 }'); resy=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $2 }'); if [[ ( $resx -lt 3000 ) || ( $resy -lt 2000 ) ]]; then echo "$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"; fi; done | xargs rm
```

In case you want to be asked for each file whether you want to delete it, use:

```
( find . -type f | xargs identify ) | grep -E '^[.][^ ]+? [^ ]+? [0-9]+?x[0-9]+? ' | sed -re 's/^([.][^ ]+?) [^ ]+? ([0-9]+?)x([0-9]+?) .*$/\2 \3 \1/g' | while read resolution; do resx=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $1 }'); resy=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $2 }'); if [[ ( $resx -lt 3000 ) || ( $resy -lt 2000 ) ]]; then echo "$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"; fi; done | xargs rm --interactive=always
```

Adding `-v` to `rm` will also print the files being deleted.

---

If you would rather not pipe it like described above, you can also delete inline:

```
( find . -type f | xargs identify ) | grep -E '^[.][^ ]+? [^ ]+? [0-9]+?x[0-9]+? ' | sed -re 's/^([.][^ ]+?) [^ ]+? ([0-9]+?)x([0-9]+?) .*$/\2 \3 \1/g' | while read resolution; do resx=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $1 }'); resy=$(echo "$resolution" | awk '{ print $2 }'); if [[ ( $resx -lt 3000 ) || ( $resy -lt 2000 ) ]]; then filetodelete=$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d ' ' -f3-); echo "$filetodelete $resx $resy"; rm -v "$filetodelete"; fi; done
```

---

**Make sure you have a backup! Don't trust the commands above to work in 100% of all scenarios.**